# USB Webcam over Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: remote-desktop, webcam, logitech-webcam

I've recently purchased a Logitech C920 webcam. For work, I RDP from my personal machine to the work laptop (located on the same LAN - It's just easier for multi-monitor setup, etc, without KVMs). Both devices are running Windows 10.

When I take part in a call (via Google Hangouts) on my work pc, I am already able to pass the audio and mic back and forth. However, I can't seem to get the webcam to pass through.

The current setup looks like this:

(Headphones + Webcam) --> Personal PC --> RDP --> Work Laptop

I've already enabled the webcam (and PnP devices) on the RDP settings:

[image: RDP Local Devices and Resources settings]

However the camera does not appear in the remote session.

[image: Remote Device Manager, Cameras Section]

Am I missing a step here? It seems like it should be working.

Comment: Any success here? I think there needs to some administrative settings changed in order to fully enable it.

Answer (score 5):

I found this solution from [another website](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1995041-anyone-using-webcams-through-thin-client-rdp-session) and it worked for me (same camera too).

On the PC you're connecting to, change the following in `Edit Group Policy`:

`Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Device and Resource Redirection`

```
Do not allow supported Plug and Play device redirection: Disabled
```

Finally, reboot the remote computer.  This is all I had to do.

The post also mentioned this setting as well, but I didn't find it necessary when going to a non-virtual machine:

`Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Remote Session Environment > RemoteFX for Windows Server 2008 R2`

```
Configure RemoteFX: Enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the group policy change as mentioned by Kcoder, I also had to ensure that the "Camera Privacy Settings" on a Windows 10 machine was also set to "Allow apps to access your camera" and "Allow desktop apps to access your camera" (on the remote computer, but it may also be necessary on the local computer).